# JPA JoinTable on OneToMany relationship with Filtering Column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two Entities, Say A and B, where in A, it has two collections of B, defined like:

```
@OneToMany
private List<B> relation1
@OneToMany
private List<B> relation2
```

I cannot put any additional column in B thus I have to use @JoinTable. My Question is:

In JPA (or Hibernate if it is not a standard one), can I use only one JoinTable but define an additional column to determine which relationship (relation1 or relation2) the row in the join table should be?

Comment: AFAIK, that's not supported, neither by JPA nor by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
@JoinTable(
    name="JOIN_TABLE_NAME",
    joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_OBJECT_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="RELATION_ONE_ID")
)
@OneToMany
private List<B> relation1;
@JoinTable(
    name="JOIN_TABLE_NAME",
    joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_OBJECT_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="RELATION_TWO_ID")
)
@OneToMany
private List<B> relation2;
```

...although I've never done something like that myself so I can't guarantee it works.